# armazenar um array de objetos em um local storage com JS

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Sou um pouco leigo com *JavaScript* e estou tentando criar um *array* de objetos para salvar dados de um formulário com o `localStorage`, mas não sei como fazer isso.

Eu já criei o código para guardar os dados no armazenamento local, porém salva apenas um objeto, sempre que eu recarrego a página e preencho os dados de novo, os dados antigos são sobrescritos.

Quero criar um *array* para colocar todos os objetos que eu criar.

**Código:**

```
function salvarPessoa(){
    var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;
    var cpf = document.getElementById("cpf").value;

    var pessoa = {nome: nome, cpf: cpf};

    pessoa_json = JSON.stringify(pessoa);

    localStorage.setItem("pessoa", pessoa_json);

    alert("Salvo com Sucesso");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

É necessário que você utilize um `array` para armazenar os valores. Para salvar no `localStorage`, basta utilizar o `JSON.stringify`.

Na captura é necessário analisar (*parse*) o objeto retornado, para isso podemos utilizar `JSON.parse`.

**Exemplo comentado:**

**JavaScript:**

```js
/**
 * Elementos
 */
const inputPeople = document.querySelector("input")
const btnSavePeople = document.querySelector("button")
const result = document.querySelector("#result ol")

/**
 * Função responsável por salvar os dados
 */
btnSavePeople.addEventListener("click", _ => {
  let peoples = new Array()

  /**
   * Verifica se a propriedade existe
   * Caso exista, converte de String para Object
   */
  if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty("peoples")) {
    peoples = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("peoples"))
  }

  /* Adiciona um novo valor no array criado */
  peoples.push({name: inputPeople.value})

  /* Salva o item */
  localStorage.setItem("peoples", JSON.stringify(peoples))

  /* Exibe o resultado */
  result.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li>${inputPeople.value}</li>`)
})


/**
 * Função responsável por carregar o conteúdo
 */
window.addEventListener("load", _ => {
  if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty("peoples")) {
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("peoples")).forEach(people => {
      result.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li>${people.name}</li>`)
    })    
  }
})
```

**HTML:**

```html
<input type="text" />
<button>Save People</button>

<div id="result"><ol></ol></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Seu código já está quase funcionando, basta apenas pegar as pessoas que já estão salvas com [`Storage.getItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem), adicionar a nova pessoa no array ([`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)) e salvar de volta ([`Storage.setItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem)).

Alterei seu código:

```js
function salvarPessoa(){
    var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;
    var cpf = document.getElementById("cpf").value;

    // Pega a lista já cadastrada, se não houver vira um array vazio
    var lista_pessoas = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('lista-pessoas') || '[]');
    // Adiciona pessoa ao cadastro
    lista_pessoas.push({
        nome: nome,
        cpf: cpf
    });

    // Salva a lista alterada
    localStorage.setItem("lista-pessoas", JSON.stringify(lista_pessoas));

    console.log('Salva com sucesso.');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Galera assim, eu conseguir resolver mas agora hostaria de saber como faço para acessar esse json para acessar as informações e criar uma função de autenticar login; minha função salvar ficou assim...

function salvarPessoa(){

```
var arrayPessoas=[]
if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("pessoas")) != null){
    arrayPessoas.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("pessoas")));
}
var nome = document.getElementById("inputNome").value;
var cpf = document.getElementById("inputCPF").value;
var idade = document.getElementById("inputIdade").value;
var telefone = document.getElementById("inputTelefone").value;
var email = document.getElementById("inputEmail").value;
var senha = document.getElementById("inputSenha").value;

var pessoa = {nome: nome, cpf: cpf, idade: idade, telefone: telefone, email: email, senha: senha};
console.log(pessoa);
arrayPessoas.push(pessoa);
var pessoaJson = JSON.stringify(arrayPessoas);
localStorage.setItem("pessoas", pessoaJson);

alert("Salvo com Sucesso");
```

}